# Print a hierarchical tree structure in javascript

Tags: javascript, tree

I'm working on a problem where given an array of file paths I would like to print the file structure. For example with the given array `["/a/b/c", "a/a/a", "/a/b/d"]`, the ideal structure would look like :

```
a
 b
  c
  d
 a
  a
```

But my structure ends up looking more like this:

```
a
 b
  c
a
 a
a
 b
```

From what I can gather this is being caused by my tree not recognizing when a node already exists in a tree. So it is adding the node "a" three times as opposed to recognizing that an "a" already exists and traversing into it.

```
let paths = ["/a/b/c", "a/a/a", "/a/b/d"]

class TreeNode {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.children = [];
    }
    
    addChild(element) {
        this.children.push(element)
    }
}

const head = new TreeNode('Head');
let cur = head;

paths.forEach(element => {
    cur = head;
    let filePath = element.split('/');
    filePath.shift();
    
    filePath.forEach(element => {
        let newNode = new TreeNode(element);
        if(!cur.children.includes(newNode)) {
            cur.addChild(newNode);
            cur = cur.children[cur.children.length - 1];
        } else {
            cur = cur.children.indexOf(newNode);
        }
    })
})

var spaceAppend = function(num) {
    let i = 0;
    let space = "";
    while(i < num) {
        space += " ";
        i++;
    }
    return space;
}

var traverse = function(node, level = 0){
    if(node === null)
        return;

    console.log(spaceAppend(level), node.value)
    if(node.children) {
        for(const n of node.children) {
            traverse(n, level + 1);
        }
    }
}

traverse(head)
```

Is there an issue with my tree implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some issues:

- `.includes()` is not the right way to find a matching value. Use `.find()` instead.
- `.indexOf()` will return an index, so that is not the right value you want to assign to `cur` in the `else` block.
- `shift` may throw away an essential part of the path when it does not start with `/`. You can ease the processing by using `.match()` instead of `.split()`, so that you get exactly the non-empty parts of the path.

Less of an issue:

- There is no need to define `cur` outside of the outer loop.
- JavaScript has a native function for something like `spaceAppend`. You can use `.repeat()`.
- `new TreeNode(element)` is also called when you actually don't need it. Only create a new node when you know there is no matching node.
- You could replace the inner `.forEach()` loop with `.reduce()`, which gives a better scope-handling for the `cur` variable.

Here is your code with those remarks taken into account:

```js
class TreeNode {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.children = [];
    }
    
    addChild(element) {
        this.children.push(element);
    }
}

let paths = ["/a/b/c", "a/a/a", "/a/b/d"];
const head = new TreeNode('Head');

paths.forEach(element => {
    // Use .match() to only get non-empty elements
    let filePath = element.match(/[^\/]+/g);
    
    filePath.reduce((cur, element) => {
        // Use .find() instead of .includes()
        let node = cur.children.find(child => child.value === element);
        // Only create the node when needed:
        if (!node) {
            node = new TreeNode(element);
            cur.addChild(node);
        }
        // Walk down one step in the tree
        return node; // ...becomes the value of `cur`
    }, head); // Initial value of reduction
});

const traverse = function(node, level=0) {
    if (node === null) return;
    // Use .repeat():
    console.log(" ".repeat(level), node.value);
    if (node.children) {
        for (const n of node.children) {
            traverse(n, level + 1);
        }
    }
}

traverse(head);
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the starter array meant to be `["/a/b/c", "/a/a/a", "/a/b/d"]` (`"/a/a/a"` instead of `("a/a/a")`?

I think the crux of the problem you're having is the line

```
if(!cur.children.includes(newNode)) { ... }
```

When a new node is created, even if it has the same `value` as a previous one, it will not result in equity when comparing the two `TreeNode` objects. You need to compare the `value` of the nodes, not the nodes themselves.

So an example with a simplified version of your node object:

```js
class TreeNode {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

a1 = new TreeNode('a');
a2 = new TreeNode('a');

console.log("a1 == a2");
console.log(a1 == a2); // false

console.log("a1.value == a2.value");
console.log(a1.value == a2.value); // true
```

I adjusted the inner forEach loop with one that compares the `value`s instead of the `TreeNode` objects

```
filePath.forEach(element => {
    let newNode = new TreeNode(element);
    let tempNode = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < cur.children.length; i++) {
      if (cur.children[i].value == newNode.value) {
        tempNode = cur.children[i];
      }
    }
    if (tempNode == null) {
      cur.addChild(newNode);
      cur = newNode;
    } else {
      cur = tempNode;
    }
});
```

[Full code snippet on codepen](https://codepen.io/blake-g/pen/MWjpMGm?editors=1010)

Object equality in javascript isn't particularly nice to deal with see [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects) for more information

Comment: Thank You! And yes, this is exactly how the problem was given to me. That's why I added the filePath.shift() to get rid of the preceding empty space

Comment: The [answer by trincot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65330241/10672141) has some more information and better practices than mine I'd say, so make sure to check their answer too

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using [lodash](https://lodash.com/) and [object-treeify](https://github.com/blackflux/object-treeify). While it's simpler code, there is obviously a trade-off introducing additional dependencies.

This solution works by first converting the paths into a tree structure and then visualizing it using object-treeify

```js
// const lodash = require('lodash');
// const objectTreeify = require('object-treeify');

const myPaths = ['/a/b/c', 'a/a/a', '/a/b/d'];

const treeify = (paths) => objectTreeify(paths.reduce((p, c) => {
  lodash.set(p, c.match(/[^/]+/g));
  return p;
}, {}), {
  spacerNoNeighbour: ' ',
  spacerNeighbour: ' ',
  keyNoNeighbour: '',
  keyNeighbour: ''
});

console.log(treeify(myPaths));
/* =>
a
 b
  c
  d
 a
  a
*/
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/lodash@4.17.20"></script>
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-treeify@1.1.31"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-treeify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-treeify)